# Code successfully runs on one machine, but on another yields "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects"

Tags: python, netcdf4

I have a script which utilizes the [Py-ART](https://github.com/ARM-DOE/pyart) package to read in airborne weather radar data and then perform quality control on said data. I'll note that I *suspect* this is not an issue with that package, otherwise I'd just post an issue to that repo...

The confusing aspect of this issue is that the code runs flawlessly on my machine, in both Python 2.x and 3.x, though it fails with the following error on a colleague's machine in Python 2.x:

`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`

The error is triggered upon trying to execute the final line of this block of code:

```
az_raw = radar.azimuth['data'].data
roll = radar.roll['data'].data
azmth = az_raw + roll
azmth[azmth < 0] += 360
```

Some potential clues I've deduced from investigating the issue:

1. On my machine, where the code runs properly, the `az_raw` and `roll` variables are read in as arrays of type `float32`, whereas on my colleague's machine, these variables have a `Buffer` type. Upon adding the contents of `roll` to `az_raw` (element-by-element), `azmth` remains as an array of `float32` on my machine, and becomes an array of `str` on the other machine.
2. Py-ART uses the [netCDF4](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html) package to read in the data from the netCDF input files - perhaps there is a machine and/or version related issue here?
3. The issue persists regardless of the input file (i.e., we've tried several, and from different data collection periods/projects with the same results.

So ultimately, my question comes down to what would cause a `TypeError` like this on one machine but not another when all else *appears* to be the same? I suppose there could be a dependency version difference (of Py-ART, netCDF4, etc.) between the two machines, but it's not clear to me how that would cause such an issue. Has anyone seen anything similar to this before?

Comment: The simplest explanation is a difference in dependency versions: try comparing the output of `pip freeze` (assuming the packages are set up through pip). As to why, well APIs can change (and sometime in a not-backwards-compatible way), and if you were not careful enough when setting up your application (you didn't fix your dependencies etc), you might have ended up with different environments on different machines.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385640/1394393

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Norrius. There is a dependency issue. How was Py-ART installed on each machine? The best way to ensure things work is to use a Conda Environment so you can control (and isolate) dependancies.

Actually now I look at the error (Buffer versus float) I know your colleague's machine has outdated packages including Numpy. If he updates numpy (this is an issue in the IO area, I think https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html, versus fromstring )

Please also note Py-ART support for Python 2.x will be dropped very soon. The next version we release, by October, will see our CI for 2.x turned off.